# Weird colors in background of UIImage when trying to replace all white colors

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage, uicolor

I have an option in my app to change the color of a button. I use a category on UIImage to do so. I wasnt looking to tint/burn the button with a certain color but replace all white(255, 255, 255) pixels with a color stored in the NSUserDefaults. The button is a shuffle icon with a transparent background. It looks like this with the white replaced with red:
[image]

I created my code from: http://brandontreb.com/image-manipulation-retrieving-and-updating-pixel-values-for-a-uiimage
Here is the code I use to replace the pixels. I put this in my UIImage category:

```
-(UIImage *)replaceWhiteWith{
    NSString *str = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"color"];
    UIColor *color = [NSString colorFromNSString:str];
    return [self replaceWithColor:color];
}

-(UIImage *) replaceWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
    CGFloat red = 0.0, green = 0.0, blue = 0.0, alpha =0.0;
    [color getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
    CGContextRef ctx;
    CGImageRef imageRef = [self CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = malloc(height * width * 4);
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    int byteIndex = 0;
    for (int ii = 0 ; ii < width * height ; ++ii)
    {
        if(rawData[byteIndex] == 255 && rawData[byteIndex+1] == 255  && rawData[byteIndex+2] == 255){
            rawData[byteIndex] = (red) * 255;
            rawData[byteIndex+1] = (green) * 255;
            rawData[byteIndex+2] = (blue) * 255;
            rawData[byteIndex+3] = (alpha) * 255;
        }

        byteIndex += 4;
    }


    ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData,
                                CGImageGetWidth( imageRef ),
                                CGImageGetHeight( imageRef ),
                                8,
                                CGImageGetBytesPerRow( imageRef ),
                                CGImageGetColorSpace( imageRef ),
                                kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast );

    imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (ctx);
    UIImage* rawImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    CGContextRelease(ctx);

    return rawImage;
}
```

Comment: How do I remove the random background pixels that weren't there before

Comment: Take a look at the image using Digital Colormeter (not sure about the name, just type "digital" in spotlight and you should find it) and make sure that all the pixels are actually 255,255,255. I'm pretty sure they are not. They might be 250,250,250 or something like that (a very light gray to get a little 3D effect).

Comment: I used Photoshop to create it and did a color overlay of 255,255,255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a different code I slipped in my loop and it no longer showed the random background static:

```
-(UIImage *)replaceWhiteWith{
    NSString *str = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"color"];
    UIColor *color = [NSString colorFromNSString:str];
    CGFloat red = 0.0, green = 0.0, blue = 0.0, alpha =0.0;
    [color getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
    CGImageRef inImage = self.CGImage;
    CFDataRef ref = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(inImage));
    UInt8 * buf = (UInt8 *) CFDataGetBytePtr(ref);
    int length = CFDataGetLength(ref);

    for(int i=0; i<length; i+=4)
    {
        int r = buf[i];
        int g = buf[i+1];
        int b = buf[i+2];
        if(r == 255 && g == 255  && b == 255){
            buf[i] = ((red) * 255);
            buf[i+1] = ((green) * 255);
            buf[i+2] = ((blue) * 255);
        }
    }

    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(buf,
                                             CGImageGetWidth(inImage),
                                             CGImageGetHeight(inImage),
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(inImage),
                                             CGImageGetBytesPerRow(inImage),
                                             CGImageGetColorSpace(inImage),
                                             CGImageGetAlphaInfo(inImage));

    CGImageRef img = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    CFRelease(ref);
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img];
}
```